# XQuery [nodes()]: Syntax error near '<eof>', expected a step expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xpath, syntax-error

Running the below SQL/XPath query returns the following error:

Query:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event' as ns
, default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'
)

select [Events].[Event].value('(./System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime)[1]','nvarchar(100)') EventTime
from @xml.nodes('/*/Event/') [Events]([Event])
```

Error:

```
XQuery [nodes()]: Syntax error near '<eof>', expected a step expression.
```

Comment: Answering my own question since I could only find one result on Google for this error & that wasn't StackOverflow.

Comment: accept that as answer, and close this question, if that worked for you

Comment: @Piyush: Will do; sadly it seems I need to wait 2 days before I'm allowed to.  My thinking had been to get it logged here to help those who end their Google searches with "site:stackoverflow.com", but it seems generally people only ask when they don't know the answer, then answer days later if no luck with the suggested answers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS-SQL-Server/Q_27789732.html

The issue was the `/` on the end of the xpath.  i.e.

```
from @xml.nodes('/*/Event/') [Events]([Event])
```

Should have been:

```
from @xml.nodes('/*/Event') [Events]([Event])
```